# Knowing who I sent a friend request to on Facebook

Tags: facebook, friends

Today I received a notification that XYZ has accepted my friend request. I do not know the person and do not remember sending any request to him.

Is there any way to check if I sent the request to him or not?

Comment: Well, Facebook only allows persons to accept requests you send, so such a list will be as well containing wrong information. A possibility would be that someone else got access to your account and sent that request.

Comment: This is what I am worried. I have changed my login credentials, but I want to make sure if this is the case.

Answer (score 5):

You can now go to the friend requests page at
https://www.facebook.com/friends/requests/ and select **"View Sent Requests"** which will take you to this page
https://www.facebook.com/friends/requests/?fcref=ff&outgoing=1.

This should give you a list of friend requests you sent.

[image: Friend Requests Sent]

Comment: Hi, if I choose cancel request, does the person get any notification?

Comment: No @anhnha, they don't. They will only be able to know you declined the friend request when they visit your profile and see that they're again able to send you a friend request. If you want to prevent this happening, you can block them.

Answer (score 1):

Even though Facebook seems to have closed the "Pending friends" API, Here is an app that you can use. I myself tried and it works.

http://apps.facebook.com/friendrequests

Answer (score 0):

I found a loophole to see pending friend requests on Facebook Timeline. Although Facebook does show you with all the friend requests received, there is no direct means to access the request you have sent from your account. But you can still keep track of them using the Facebook’s “Download Your Information” option. Follow:

1. Go to your '**Account Settings**'
2. Click on '**Download a Copy of your Facebook data**' on bottom of page.
3. Select '**expanded archive**' from the link below.
4. After entering your Password, click on '**Start My Archive**'
5. Once the archive is ready, you will receive an email. Now you need to **download** the archive from the link. (Usually takes 1 to 2 hours)
6. Extract downloaded zip file and Open **index.html**
7. Then navigate to “**Pending friend requests**” link. Click that link, now you can see the whole pending friend requests list on 'Pending Sent Friend Requests' head. It will also shows you the 'Pending Received Friend Requests'. You can also view friends whom you have deleted from your account.

You're done! c:

For detailed tutorial with screenshots, visit:http://www.sociobits.org/2013/04/view-your-pending-friend-requests-on-facebook-timeline-may-2013.html

Answer (score 0):

https://www.facebook.com/friends/requests/?fcref=ff&outgoing=1

Just click this link to get your list of outgoing Friend Requests.

Answer (score -1):

You can install a script such as [Unfriend Finder](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/58852) to track activities regarding friend requests. It will also notify you when someone ignores your request, remove from you from his/her friend list, activate/deactivate his/her facebook account. Pretty handy.

Comment: That userscript is 404. Unfriend Finder has been discontinued.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to send a befriending message to each and every request you send out from now on...And then just scroll through your sent messages....you will know everything you need to know.....:)