# List of people who have not yet accepted my friend request

Tags: facebook, friends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Knowing who I sent a friend request to on Facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16451/knowing-who-i-sent-a-friend-request-to-on-facebook)

How can I list people to whom I've sent a Facebook friend request that they have not yet accepted?

Answer (score 2):

Per Facebook help:

> There's currently no place on the site where you can see all your sent pending requests. However, if you go to someone's profile (timeline) you can tell your friend status based on the following.
>
> - If you see **Add as Friend**, then you don't have a friend request pending.
> - If you see **Awaiting friend confirmation**, you'll know that you've sent a request that hasn't yet been confirmed.
> - If you see the **Remove friend** link, you'll know you've both confirmed your friendship.

However, there some scripts like [Unfriend Finder](http://www.unfriendfinder.com) that can track your pending friend requests as long as you add people *after* the script is installed.

Comment: "Unfriend Finder is no longer available"